# Whats the difference between pyethapp and pyethereum?

Tags: pyethereum, pyethapp

This one:
https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp

and this one:
https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum

I have pyethapp running (the ipython console). What then is pyethereum?

Answer (score 9):

Pyethereum is the core blockchain related logic: transactions, blocks, contract VM, etc....

Pyethapp uses both [pydevp2p](https://github.com/ethereum/pydevp2p) for the p2p logic along with Pyethereum to create a complete Ethereum client.

So if you want a complete networked Ethereum client use Pyethapp. If you just want to experiment with the blockchain related logic you can use Pyethereum by itself.

Comment: So with pyethapp i also have pyethereum, so to speak.

Comment: Yes.  Pyethapp contains pyethereum and pydevp2p. See the README for more details: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp

Comment: So if i have pyethereum (since i have pyethapp running), do I then also have pyethtool?

Comment: I'm *think* pyethtool is the name of an older tool that's been moved within Pyethereum.   So I'm sure you have the same functionality by having Pyethereum.

Comment: I'm asking because of this tutorial: https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/04/10/pyethereum-and-serpent-programming-guide/